# WCF ChannelFactory and OperationBehavior

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, channelfactory

I have a service contract as follow

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
     [MyCustomBehavior]
     [OperationContract]
     void MyOperation();
}
```

The question is whether a call to

```
 new ChannelFactory<IService>(myBinding, myUri)
```

Will implicitly add MyCustomBehavior before the call, just by virtue of me passing the IService to the ChannelFactory or will I need to dig deeper and explicitly set MyCustomBehavior to the MyOperation operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Operation Behaviors**
>
> Operation behaviors, which implement the IOperationBehavior interface,
>   are used to extend both the client and service runtime for each
>   operation.
>
> There are two mechanisms for adding operation behaviors to an
>   operation. The first mechanism is to create a custom attribute to be
>   used on the method that models the operation. When an operation is
>   added to either a ServiceHost or a ChannelFactory, WCF adds any
>   IOperationBehavior attributes to the behaviors collection on the
>   OperationDescription created for that operation.
>
> The second mechanism is by directly adding the behavior to the
>   behaviors collection on a constructed OperationDescription.

I will suggest you to read this first.

[Configuring and Extending the Runtime with Behaviors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730137.aspx)